# LDAP & Java: how to check if PagedResultsControl and/or VLV are available

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I need to implement paging for large LDAP result sets, i.e. per here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html

**Not all Equal**

This comment, while old, points to the fact that different LDAP implementation do not all support this mechanism:

*The Paged Search Control is supported by the Windows Active Directory Server. It's not supported by the Oracle Directory Server version 5.2*

A more recent post shows that Oracle Directory Server supports an alternate mechanism Virtual List Views (vlv).
https://blogs.oracle.com/kanthi/entry/directory_server_and_ldap_paged

**Design**

For implementation, I'd like to try one mechanism, then if it fails try another. (rather than if-AD-do-this-if-Oracle-do-that)

**Question**

How, in java, can I check if the currently LDAP/Directory instance supports either PagedControls or VLV? i.e. what code can I execute and exception can I check to know whether it supports one or the other?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways.

1. Try it and cope with the exception. This is probably the best.
2. You can look up the `supportedControl` and `supportedExtension` attributes of the root object. The OID for VLV is `2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.9`. The OID for the Paged Results Control is `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319.` If the OID is present in the `supportControl` attribute, the corresponding feature is supported.

Comment: Do you have the specific exception to catch? i.e. a PagingNotSupportedException vs a general LDAP exception.  I'm actually trying to code "to spec". I'm also concerned that different implementations might throw different exceptions if a control isn't supported.

Comment: I believe it is javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException, but you would have to test and verify.

Answer (score 0):

To build on user207421's answer, I was able to perform option 2 using the following method:

```
private boolean isPagingSupported(DirContext dirContext)
        throws NamingException {

    Hashtable<?,?> environment = dirContext.getEnvironment();
    URI uri = URI.create("" +  environment.get("java.naming.provider.url"));
    final String rootDse = uri.getScheme() + "://" + uri.getAuthority();

    final Attributes attributes = dirContext.getAttributes(rootDse, new String[]{"supportedControl"});

    final NamingEnumeration attributeValues = attributes.getAll();
    while(attributeValues.hasMore()) {
        final Attribute attribute = (Attribute) attributeValues.next();
        final NamingEnumeration supportedControls = attribute.getAll();
        while(supportedControls.hasMore()) {
            String supportedControl = (String) supportedControls.next();
            if(supportedControl.equals(PAGING_OID)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Some notes:

- The concept of controls was not added until [LDAP v3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2251.txt). This method of checking the `supportedControl` attribute (also not added until v3) won't work on earlier versions. Earlier versions can be assumed to not support paging.
- `PAGING_OID` is set to `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319` as user207421 suggested.
- I pass `uri.getScheme() + "://" + uri.getAuthority()` as the name of the root DSE, which seems to work in all cases. `java.naming.provider.url` might contain some configured base DN in its path (e.g. `ldap://my-server:389/ou=users,dc=mycompany,dc=org`), so it is necessary to use only the scheme and authority.
- I use this code with Spring by taking an Autowired `ContextSource` object and passing it's `getReadOnlyContext()` output:

  ```
    boolean pagingSupported = isPagingSupported(contextSource.getReadOnlyContext())
  ```

Further reading:

- [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5580/6jej518p5/index.html). Note that this documentation also mentions checking for `2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.2`, which is not necessary.